# When ROS support ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit?

Tags: ros, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When ROS support ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/159946/when-ros-support-ubuntu-14.04-lts-64bit-??/) by [Robotics123](https://answers.ros.org/users/15496/robotics123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When [Indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo) is release which should be by the end of this month.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robotics123](https://answers.ros.org/users/15496/robotics123/) on 2014-05-02**:
Thanks tonybaltovski

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-05-02**:
@Robotics123 you can choose the answer as "answered" by clicking the check sign.